# Is `ip` to supersede `ifconfig`

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, tcpip, ifconfig

A friend of mine said that [`ip`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip) is supposed to be the successor of `ifconfig` <s>and `iwconfig`</s> — yet I found no Wikipedia article about it and have never seen anyone mention or recommend it online even though it's from the year 2002 according to its man page. That indicates that it's not much used.

The name `ip` is difficult to Google so I decided to ask here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The ip command is part of the iproute2 collection of utilities.**

According to the [Linux Foundation](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2) the ifconfig command should be deprecated, but most distros still include them.  iproute2 also contains the tc (traffic control) command.  See usage information by using the `$ man ip` command.

There was a discussion about this on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/q/42047/51946) last year.

Comment: `ifconfig`, not `ipconfig`.

Comment: @joschi Thanks for catching that.  I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

IP is a newer subset of commands that is meant to take the place of ifconfig, some examples:

```
ip link show    List network interfaces
ip link set dev eth0 name wan   Rename interface eth0 to wan
ip link set dev eth0 up Bring interface eth0 up (or down)
ip addr show    List addresses for interfaces
ip addr add 1.2.3.4/24 brd + dev eth0   Add (or del) ip and mask (255.255.255.0)
ip route show   List routing table
ip route add default via 1.2.3.254  Set default gateway to 1.2.3.254
```